# General forms of conditional heteroskedasticity

Tags: heteroscedasticity

I am currently reading a paper published in the Journal of Finance:

Rapach et al. (2013), 'International Stock Return Predictability. What is the role of the United States'.

The authors quote they use a wild-bootstrap procedure for inference which accounts for general forms of conditional heteroskedasticity.

I am wondering if anyone could shed light on the term general forms of conditional heteroskedasticity as opposed to what other forms?

Comment: why did you downvote it?

Comment: I've noticed a few other questions that have unexplained, and indeed inexplicable, downvotes this morning my time... not sure what's going on, but I wouldn't take it personally.  I'm upvoting to counteract the downvote.

Comment: Thanks @jbowman